# printing multiple values using pointer in printf

Tags: c

I am unable to findout the problem with the code below. I get warning message "operation on 'ptr' may be undefined" on printf statement. Also the the result is printed in reverse order (7 is printed aganst Element1 and 2 against element2)

```
int main()
{
    int a[4] = {2,7,9,0};
    int *ptr=a;
    printf("Element1 = %d Element 2 = %d", *ptr, *ptr++);
    ptr++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you write this garbage, lift it fron your homework or copy it from some book or site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard does not define in what order the parameters get evaluated. Try using *(ptr+1) instead of *ptr++, which also can be replaced with ptr[1].

Comment: Nor does it define when the increment occurs beyond 'before the actual call to `printf()` occurs'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and most implementations evaluate the parameters form right to left, no?

Comment: @A.S.H:  I don't know which order implementations evaluate their arguments; I've never bothered to investigate since the behaviour can change from system to system, compiler to compiler, version to version, or even at the whim of the compiler during a single compilation.  It isn't useful information to me — I'd suggest you're better off not knowing as well, and ensuring that your code works correctly regardless of which order the compiler chooses.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with you, it's only that i remembered the days when we studied how C pushed the parameters in reverse order, and that was a design choice precisely to permit the implementation of printf. But you are right, better not know and not count on it.

Comment: Just curious: Why latest C compilers does not take care of such issues? Why C has lot of undefined behavior (or so called features) which may add more bugs to the code? Do we have any good C compilers that take care of all such issues?

Comment: I believe this gives compilers a freedom to optimize their behaviour. It would be hard to formalize except for simplest cases anyway, and consequently hard to remember for the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no [sequenceing or specified evaluation order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) for function arguments so you don't know which argument will be evaluated first, `*ptr` or `*ptr++` (or even the string literal), which leads to *undefined behavior*.